# bash git function for parse_git_branch

Tags: git, parsing, branch

I'm trying to add a function for git inside the .bashrc file but when I do I get errors.

Here is the function inside the .bashrc file:

```
function parse_git_branch() {
  BRANCH=`git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'`
  if [ ! "${BRANCH}" == "" ]
  then
    STAT=`parse_git_dirty`
    echo "[${BRANCH}${STAT}]"
  else
    echo ""
  fi
}

# get current status of git repo
function parse_git_dirty {
  status=`git status 2>&1 | tee`
  dirty=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "modified:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
  untracked=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "Untracked files" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
  ahead=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "Your branch is ahead of" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
  newfile=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "new file:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
  renamed=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "renamed:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
  deleted=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "deleted:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
  bits=''
  if [ "${renamed}" == "0" ]; then
    bits=">${bits}"
  fi
  if [ "${ahead}" == "0" ]; then
    bits="*${bits}"
  fi
  if [ "${newfile}" == "0" ]; then
    bits="+${bits}"
  fi
  if [ "${untracked}" == "0" ]; then
    bits="?${bits}"
  fi
  if [ "${deleted}" == "0" ]; then
    bits="x${bits}"
  fi
  if [ "${dirty}" == "0" ]; then
    bits="!${bits}"
  fi
  if [ ! "${bits}" == "" ]; then
    echo " ${bits}"
  else
    echo ""
  fi
}
```

These are the errors I get when running .bashrc are:

bash-4.2$ exec bash

bash: /home/centos/.bashrc: line 33: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''

'ash: /home/centos/.bashrc: line 33: `function parse_git_branch() {

bash-4.2$

Comment: Maybe you should run "source ~/.bashrc". I have no problem with your bash script.

Comment: same result.  Do you want to see my full .basrc file?

Comment: The `\r` and the fact that the single quote overwrote the letter `b` in `bash` suggest that you've saved your file with CRLF line endings. Bash does not read such files.

Comment: The first line in `parse_git_branch` can be replaced by : `BRANCH=$(git branch --show-current)`